# Plotting $\frac{1}{d}\frac{\sum_{ij}^d(i^{-p}-j^{-p})^2}{\left(\sum_i^d i^{-p}\right)^2}$ for large $d$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, performance-tuning

I'm trying to understand large $d$ behavior for $F(p,d)$ with $1\le p\le 2$ and $d>10^6$

$$F(p, d)=\frac{1}{d}\frac{\sum_{ij}^d(i^{-p}-j^{-p})^2}{\left(\sum_i^d i^{-p}\right)^2}$$

The following code works, but doesn't scale for large $d$, can someone see a way to get this to get this plotted for large $d$?

```
Clear[h, i, j];
var[p_, d_] := (
   h[i_] = i^-p;
   1/d NSum[(h[i] - h[j])^2, {i, 1, d}, {j, 1, d}]/
    NSum[h[i], {i, 1, d}]^2
   );
DiscretePlot[{var[1., d], var[1.5, d], var[2., d]}, {d, 1., 20, 1.}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"d", "value"}, PlotLegends -> {"p=1", "p=1.5", "p=2"}]
```

[image]

I'm interested in finding what the limit is, and how long it takes to get there as a function of $p$

Motivation: this gives variance of $f(x)=x_1/1^p + x_2/2^p + x_3/3^p+\ldots+x_d/d^p$ evaluated at a random point $x$ on a sphere of radius chosen such that expected value $E[f(x)]=1$ (variance formula from [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/532117/distribution-of-langle-x2-a-rangle-where-x-is-is-a-random-direction/532222#532222)). The case for $p=1$ is worked out [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4183090/998), I'm trying to get the $p>1$ case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you change `NSum` to `Sum`, then you get

```
var[p_, d_] := (h[i_] = i^-p;
   1/d Sum[(h[i] - h[j])^2, {i, 1, d}, {j, 1, d}]/Sum[h[i], {i, 1, d}]^2);
```

with the general result

```
var[p, d]
(* -((2 (HarmonicNumber[d, p]^2 - d HarmonicNumber[d, 2 p]))/(d HarmonicNumber[d, p]^2)) *)
```

The limit with $p=2$ as $d \rightarrow\infty$ is

```
Limit[-((2 (HarmonicNumber[d, 2]^2 - d HarmonicNumber[d, 4]))/(d HarmonicNumber[d, 2]^2)), d -> ∞]
(* 4/5 *)
```

Based on the comment from @UlrichNeuman a more general result can be obtained:

```
Limit[var[p, d], d -> ∞, Assumptions -> p > 1]
(* (2 Zeta[2 p])/Zeta[p]^2 *)
```

Using *Mathematica* 13.2.0.0 on Windows 10 I get the following for $0\leq p\leq 1$:

```
Limit[var[p, d], d -> ∞, Assumptions -> 0 <= p <= 1]
```

[image: result for restricted range of p]

I don't know why the rest of the range of $p$ is not included but the complete range can be covered with

```
Limit[var[p, d], d -> ∞, Assumptions -> 0 <= p <= 1/2]
(* 0 *)
```

and

```
Limit[var[p, d], d -> ∞, Assumptions -> 2/3 <= p <= 1]
```

[image: Limit for 2/3 <= p <= 1]

Comment: Perhaps `Asymptotic[var[p, d], d -> Infinity, Assumptions -> 1 < p < 2]` gives `(2 Zeta[2 p])/Zeta[p]^2` might complete your answer

Comment: Thanks, @UlrichNeumann!

Answer (score 4):

If $F(p, d)=\frac{1}{d}\frac{\sum_{ij}^d(i^{-p}-j^{-p})^2}{\left(\sum_i^d i^{-p}\right)^2}$, then asymptotically $F(p,d) = \frac{2 \zeta (2 p)}{\zeta (p)^2} + O(1/d)$. So the asymptotic answer is $\lim_{d->\infty} F(p,d) = \frac{2 \zeta (2 p)}{\zeta (p)^2}$.

`2 Zeta[2 p]/Zeta[p]^2 /. p -> 2`

`4/5`

`2 Zeta[2 p]/Zeta[p]^2 /. p -> 1.5`

`0.352277`

Answer (score 3):

This makes me think that one should consider using mathematics instead of Mathematica:

```
Compile[{{d, _Integer}, {p, _Real}},
   Block[{hh},
    hh = Range[1., d]^-p;
    1/d Total[Total[(hh - #)^2] & /@ hh]/Total[hh]^2
    ]][10^6, 1.5] // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {219.747, 0.352815}  *)
```

But maybe it's fast enough....

Comment: Interesting, plotting it for $d=10^5,p=2$ gives result suspiciously close to $4/5$ so there might be a simple closed form solution, [posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4713352/computing-lim-d-to-infty-frac1d-frac-sum-i-j-1-1d-lefti-p-j) on math.SE